# Adding Sharepoint 2007/2010 ontop of TFS 2010

Tags: tfs, sharepoint-2007, installation

So I finally have everything up and running and everyone is mostly happy - TFS 2010 rocks!

However now I want to add office sharepoint, I didn't want to have it installed first because I was worried that it would stuff with things and I wanted to look back on the TFS installation, once I knew how portals were created.

So what is the best way to now add sharepoint to the installation without stuffing things up?
I have a 2 server environment, with TFS on one and the database on another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get SharePoint up on whatever server you want it running on.  Install the TFS extensions on the SharePoint server, this will give it the site templates and connectors it needs to integrate with TFS.  Then, go to the TFS admin console and create the connection to your SharePoint instance (should just be the url http://mysharepointserver).  Then, if you create a new team project, you can just select that you want it to automatically create a new project portal for it on SharePoint, and you can specify the location.  If you already have a team project, then you'll need to manually create a new project site in SharePoint, then just connect it back to whatever TFS project you want it to pull the lists from.